# No GUI after login following upgrade to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, virtualization

My machine was running an earlier version of Ubuntu. I chose to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. The system was **powered down** multiple times during the process. Initially I had issues with login looping and lost account password but this was resolved.

Now I get the GUI login screen, but once logged in it shows nothing.

The terminal works and I can access and confirm account info.
But I am not sure about the critical files and programs in **VMWARE** and also other files likely stored in folders other than `/home`. The system contains years of my research work.

How to bring back the Graphical User Interface?

Additional notes:
I was able to see previous files via live-Ubuntu session. I also connected hard-disk to another PC to confirm apparent existence of files.

Comment: Please list out the issues your are facing.

Comment: Thanks George,  at the core of it all, I need to recover data that was in her VM under Ubuntu.  Ideally I would want to properly install Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, and still have access to previous data and applications.  I have worked at updating security settings on her "Home" with much success, and copied those files, but I truly believe some key elements were stored outside the Home directory, and I am concerned that installing the updated OS may over write or loose data.